# dropdown menu icon img not working (trying to replace '+' with img)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

```js
/* global ethemeScreenReaderText */
/**
 * Theme functions file.
 *
 * Contains handlers for navigation and widget area.
 */

(function( $ ) {
 var masthead, menuToggle, siteNavigation;

 function initMainNavigation( container ) {

  // Add dropdown toggle that displays child menu items.
  var dropdownToggle = $( '<button />', { 'class': 'dropdown-toggle', 'aria-expanded': false })
   .append( $( '<span />', { 'class': 'dropdown-symbol', text: '+' }) )
   .append( $( '<span />', { 'class': 'screen-reader-text', text: ethemeScreenReaderText.expand }) );

  container.find( '.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a' ).after( dropdownToggle );

  container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click( function( e ) {
   var _this = $( this ),
    screenReaderSpan = _this.find( '.screen-reader-text' );
    dropdownSymbol = _this.find( '.dropdown-symbol' );
    dropdownSymbol.text( dropdownSymbol.text() === '-' ? '+' : '-');

   e.preventDefault();
   _this.toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
   _this.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );

   _this.attr( 'aria-expanded', _this.attr( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false' );

   screenReaderSpan.text( screenReaderSpan.text() === ethemeScreenReaderText.expand ? ethemeScreenReaderText.collapse : ethemeScreenReaderText.expand );
  });

  
 }

 initMainNavigation( $( '.main-navigation' ) );

 masthead       = $( '#masthead' );
 menuToggle     = masthead.find( '.menu-toggle' );
 siteNavigation = masthead.find( '.main-navigation > div > ul' );

 // Enable menuToggle.
 (function() {

  // Return early if menuToggle is missing.
  if ( ! menuToggle.length ) {
   return;
  }

  // Add an initial values for the attribute.
  menuToggle.add( siteNavigation ).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );

  menuToggle.on( 'click.etheme', function() {
   $( siteNavigation.closest( '.main-navigation' ), this ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );

   $( this )
    .add( siteNavigation )
    .attr( 'aria-expanded', $( this ).add( siteNavigation ).attr( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false' );
  });
 })();

 // Fix sub-menus for touch devices and better focus for hidden submenu items for accessibility.
 (function() {
  if ( ! siteNavigation.length || ! siteNavigation.children().length ) {
   return;
  }

  // Toggle `focus` class to allow submenu access on tablets.
  function toggleFocusClassTouchScreen() {
   if ( 'none' === $( '.menu-toggle' ).css( 'display' ) ) {

    $( document.body ).on( 'touchstart.etheme', function( e ) {
     if ( ! $( e.target ).closest( '.main-navigation li' ).length ) {
      $( '.main-navigation li' ).removeClass( 'focus' );
     }
    });

    siteNavigation.find( '.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a' )
     .on( 'touchstart.etheme', function( e ) {
      var el = $( this ).parent( 'li' );

      if ( ! el.hasClass( 'focus' ) ) {
       e.preventDefault();
       el.toggleClass( 'focus' );
       el.siblings( '.focus' ).removeClass( 'focus' );
      }
     });

   } else {
    siteNavigation.find( '.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a' ).unbind( 'touchstart.etheme' );
   }
  }

  if ( 'ontouchstart' in window ) {
   $( window ).on( 'resize.etheme', toggleFocusClassTouchScreen );
   toggleFocusClassTouchScreen();
  }

  siteNavigation.find( 'a' ).on( 'focus.etheme blur.etheme', function() {
   $( this ).parents( '.menu-item, .page_item' ).toggleClass( 'focus' );
  });
 })();

 // Add the default ARIA attributes for the menu toggle and the navigations.
 function onResizeARIA() {
  if ( 'block' === $( '.menu-toggle' ).css( 'display' ) ) {

   if ( menuToggle.hasClass( 'toggled-on' ) ) {
    menuToggle.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
   } else {
    menuToggle.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
   }

   if ( siteNavigation.closest( '.main-navigation' ).hasClass( 'toggled-on' ) ) {
    siteNavigation.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
   } else {
    siteNavigation.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
   }
  } else {
   menuToggle.removeAttr( 'aria-expanded' );
   siteNavigation.removeAttr( 'aria-expanded' );
   menuToggle.removeAttr( 'aria-controls' );
  }
 }

 $( document ).ready( function() {
  $( window ).on( 'load.etheme', onResizeARIA );
  $( window ).on( 'resize.etheme', onResizeARIA );
 });

})( jQuery );
```

```css
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Menus
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*c */
.main-navigation {
 display: block;
  clear: left;
  background-color: #fff;
/*  background-color: #28406d;
*/ }
.dropdown-symbol {
 color: black;
}
 
@media screen and (max-width: 601px) {
/* .main-navigation {
   margin-top: 40px;
 }*/
 .main-navigation li a {
  padding:1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 } 

}



@media screen and (max-width: 729px) {
 .menu-primar-container {
  background-color: #28406d;
  position: relative;
  top: 29px;
   padding: 1rem;
  }
  .main-navigation > a {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
   color:#fff;
  }

  .site-branding {
   position: relative;
   width: 50%;
   /*left: 30px;*/
  }


}

@media only screen and (max-width: 902px) and (min-width: 603px)  {
 .main-navigation {
  position: absolute;
     top: 80px;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
 }
}

/*@media screen and (max-width: 902px) {
 .main-navigation {
  position: absolute;
     top: 109px;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
 }
}
*/
.main-navigation ul {
 display: none;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 1em;
 padding-left: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
 display: none;
 top: 1.5em;
 z-index: 99999;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul {
 top: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li {
 padding-left: 1em;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul,
        .main-navigation ul ul li:focus > ul {
 left: 100%;
 top:0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul a {
 /*width: 200px;*/
 border-bottom: 2px solid green;

}

.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
    .main-navigation ul li.focus > ul {
 left: auto;
}

.main-navigation li {
 position: relative;
}

.main-navigation a {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: .5em 1em .5em 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 font-size: 1.1rem;
 font-weight: bolder;
 border-bottom: 3px #a7db51 solid;
}



.main-navigation a:hover,
  .main-navigation a:focus {
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.main-navigation .menu-item-has-children,
  .main-navigation .page_item_has_children {
 min-width: 218px;
}

.main-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a,
  .main-navigation .page_item_has_children > a {
 padding-right: 2em;
}

button.dropdown-toggle {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 border: none;
 background: inherit;
 color: white;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 padding: .4em 1em .4em .5em;
}  

/* Burger Nav */
#sidebar-btn {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
 height: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin:6px;
  position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 
}
#sidebar-btn span {
 height: 2px;
 background: black;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 display: block;
}
#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2) {
 width: 75%;
}
#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3) {
 width: 50%;
}

.menu-toggle {
 z-index: 11;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 display: block;
 margin: 1.8rem;
 background-color: white;
/* padding: .6em .8em;
*/ font-size: 80%;
 text-transform: uppercase;
/* color: white;
*/  
/* border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
*/}

/* Toggle small menu and children on */
.toggled-on ul,
.sub-menu.toggled-on {
 display: block;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
 .menu-toggle {
  display: none;
 }

 .main-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a,
   .main-navigation .page_item_has_children > a {
  padding-right: 2em;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 }

 .main-navigation ul {
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
 
 }

 .main-navigation ul ul {
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: 43px;
  /*background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);*/
  margin-left: 0;
 }

 .main-navigation ul ul li {
  padding-left: 0;
 }

 .main-navigation ul ul li a {
  width: 218px;
  /*background: none;*/
 }

 .main-navigation ul li a {
  padding: .4em 1em;
 }


}
/* CONTROL SUB MENU ON HOVER DISPLAY */
/*.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 top: 3.5rem;
 background-color: #28406d;
}
*/
@media screen and (min-width: 904px) {
 .main-navigation ul {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-top: 0;
 }
 
 /* If you want dropdowns to open on hover, uncomment this: */
 .main-navigation ul  li:hover > ul, .main-navigation ul li:focus > ul, .main-navigation ul li:hover > ul  {
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  z-index: 12;
   display: block;
       background-color: #fff;

    }
 

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle">
     <div id="sidebar-btn">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>    
     </div>   
    </button> 
    <div class="menu-test-container"><ul id="primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-2035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2035"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Services</a><button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false"><span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span><span class="screen-reader-text">Expand child menu</span></button>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-2076" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2076"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Commercial</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-2079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2079"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/">Residential</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-2082" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2082"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Rural</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-2081" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2081"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Electrical</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-2083" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2083"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-2078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2078"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2084" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2084"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Projects</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2045"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/blog/">Blog</a></li>
</ul></div>   </nav>
```

So i want to add a drop down icon for my navbar item.

> **Currently**: At the moment it is showing characters '+' and '-' when
>   menu is opened/closed.

**The problem: I am using `dropdownSymbol.text( dropdownSymbol.text() === '-' ? '+' : '-');`**

**Issue: I am not sure how to replace an image icon for '+'/ '-'. I have tried to add image tag there but its not working.**

**NAV.JS**

```
    (function( $ ) {
    var masthead, menuToggle, siteNavigation;

    function initMainNavigation( container ) {

    // Add dropdown toggle that displays child menu items.
    var dropdownToggle = $( '<button />', { 'class': 'dropdown-toggle', 'aria-expanded': false })
    .append( $( '<span />', { 'class': 'dropdown-symbol', text: '+' }) )
    .append( $( '<span />', { 'class': 'screen-reader-text', text: ethemeScreenReaderText.expand }) );

    container.find( '.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a' ).after( dropdownToggle );

    container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click( function( e ) {
    var _this = $( this ),
    screenReaderSpan = _this.find( '.screen-reader-text' );
    dropdownSymbol = _this.find( '.dropdown-symbol' );
    dropdownSymbol.text( dropdownSymbol.text() === '-' ? '+' : '-');

    e.preventDefault();
    _this.toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
    _this.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );

    _this.attr( 'aria-expanded', _this.attr( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false' );

    screenReaderSpan.text( screenReaderSpan.text() === ethemeScreenReaderText.expand ? ethemeScreenReaderText.collapse : ethemeScreenReaderText.expand );
});


}

initMainNavigation( $( '.main-navigation' ) );

masthead       = $( '#masthead' );
menuToggle     = masthead.find( '.menu-toggle' );
siteNavigation = masthead.find( '.main-navigation > div > ul' );

// Enable menuToggle.
(function() {

// Return early if menuToggle is missing.
if ( ! menuToggle.length ) {
return;
}

// Add an initial values for the attribute.
menuToggle.add( siteNavigation ).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );

menuToggle.on( 'click.etheme', function() {
$( siteNavigation.closest( '.main-navigation' ), this ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );

$( this )
.add( siteNavigation )
.attr( 'aria-expanded', $( this ).add( siteNavigation ).attr( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false' );
});
})();

// Fix sub-menus for touch devices and better focus for hidden submenu items for accessibility.
(function() {
if ( ! siteNavigation.length || ! siteNavigation.children().length ) {
return;
}

// Toggle `focus` class to allow submenu access on tablets.
function toggleFocusClassTouchScreen() {
if ( 'none' === $( '.menu-toggle' ).css( 'display' ) ) {

$( document.body ).on( 'touchstart.etheme', function( e ) {
if ( ! $( e.target ).closest( '.main-navigation li' ).length ) {
$( '.main-navigation li' ).removeClass( 'focus' );
}
});

siteNavigation.find( '.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a' )
.on( 'touchstart.etheme', function( e ) {
var el = $( this ).parent( 'li' );

if ( ! el.hasClass( 'focus' ) ) {
e.preventDefault();
el.toggleClass( 'focus' );
el.siblings( '.focus' ).removeClass( 'focus' );
}
});

} else {
siteNavigation.find( '.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a' ).unbind( 'touchstart.etheme' );
}
}

if ( 'ontouchstart' in window ) {
$( window ).on( 'resize.etheme', toggleFocusClassTouchScreen );
toggleFocusClassTouchScreen();
}

siteNavigation.find( 'a' ).on( 'focus.etheme blur.etheme', function() {
$( this ).parents( '.menu-item, .page_item' ).toggleClass( 'focus' );
});
})();

// Add the default ARIA attributes for the menu toggle and the navigations.
function onResizeARIA() {
if ( 'block' === $( '.menu-toggle' ).css( 'display' ) ) {

if ( menuToggle.hasClass( 'toggled-on' ) ) {
menuToggle.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
} else {
menuToggle.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
}

if ( siteNavigation.closest( '.main-navigation' ).hasClass( 'toggled-on' ) ) {
siteNavigation.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
} else {
siteNavigation.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
}
} else {
menuToggle.removeAttr( 'aria-expanded' );
siteNavigation.removeAttr( 'aria-expanded' );
menuToggle.removeAttr( 'aria-controls' );
}
}

$( document ).ready( function() {
$( window ).on( 'load.etheme', onResizeARIA );
$( window ).on( 'resize.etheme', onResizeARIA );
});

})( jQuery );
```

**HTML**

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle">
        <div id="sidebar-btn">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>               
        </div>   
    </button> 
    <div class="menu-test-container"><ul id="primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-2035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2009 current_page_item current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-2035"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Services</a><button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false"><span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span><span class="screen-reader-text">Expand child menu</span></button>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-2076" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2076"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Commercial</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2079"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/">Residential</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2082" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2082"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Rural</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2081" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2009 current_page_item menu-item-2081"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Electrical</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2083" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2083"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2078"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">About</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2084" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2084"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Projects</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2045"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/blog/">Blog</a></li>
</ul></div></nav>
```

Comment: provide fiddle please

Comment: I've added a fiddle, please click on full page to see the navbar. the css properties seem to be off so the + sign is margin off, but you'll get it. ideas?

Comment: which plugin r u using can post a link

Comment: it is code a plugin. its code used from a tutorial..

Comment: any ideas what the solution is?